# R: Changing axis title of all graphs with grid.arrange & Forcing non-scientific notation in labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

Below is my code for 2 graphs, the current output is shown below as well. I've been trying to do 2 things:

- Changing the axis label so that it is only noted once for both graphs (& centred preferrably).
- Forcing non-scientific notation (Notice how it's fine everywhere apart from on the y-axi where it shows `1e-04`).

## My code

```
make_linear_regression <- function(){
  linear_scat_um <- filtered_data %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = log10(rel_wpm), y= log10(rel_um))) +
    geom_point(alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_smooth(method = lm, color = "red") +
    labs(title = "Voorkomens van 'eh'",
         x = "Relatief Aantal Woorden Per Minuut",
         y = "Hoeveel procent van spraak is 'eh'?") +
    theme_fivethirtyeight() +
    theme(axis.title = element_text(),
          plot.title = element_text(colour = "#FF0000"),
          axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(-2,-1,0,1,2),
                       labels = c(0.01,0.1,1,10,100))+
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(-4,-3,-2,-1),
                       labels = c(0.0001,0.001,0.01,0.1)) 
  
  
  linear_scat_uhm <- filtered_data %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=log10(rel_wpm), y=log10(rel_uhm))) +
    geom_point(alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_smooth(method = lm, color = "blue") +
    labs(title = "Voorkomens van 'ehm'",
         x = "Relatief Aantal Woorden Per Minuut",
         y = "Hoeveel procent van spraak is 'ehm'?") +
    theme_fivethirtyeight() +
    theme(axis.title = element_text(),
          plot.title = element_text(colour = "#0000FF"),
          axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(-2,-1,0,1,2),
                       labels = c(0.01,0.1,1,10,100)) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(-4,-3,-2,-1),
                       labels = c(0.0001,0.001,0.01,0.1)) 
  
  
  grid.arrange(linear_scat_um, linear_scat_uhm)
```

## Current output

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ieOi.png)

## What I've already tried.

#### Single axis title.

- I found a couple of posts using `textGrub` but that doesn't seem to work, I know for sure I have the library installed but it cannot find the function.

#### Forcing non-scientific notation.

- Using `label_comma()` does change the notation to numbers, but it also changes the values I give. it would put the breaks in front of the decimal, leading to the y-labels: -4.0000, -3.000, -2.00, -1.0).

Comment: For the labels try `labels = ~ scales::comma(10^.x)`. For the axis title. Remove it from each plot using `labs(y = NULL)` then try `grid.arrange(..., left = "TITLE")`.

Comment: @stefan Thank you! The change to the grid.arrange worked! However I cannot seem to figure out how to make the labels work. When I try `scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma(10^.log10(rel_um)))` it gives me the following error: `Error in .log10(rel_um) : could not find function ".log10"` which is strange to me as I use log10() in the same function.

Comment: Try `10^log10()` without the dot `.x` is a special notation. But as your breaks are c(-4, -3, -2, ...) using `10^.x` as I suggested should give you the desired labels `.0001, .001, .01, ...`.

Comment: I think I'm not doing it correctly then. I've tried `scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(-4,-3,-2,-1),
                      labels = c(0.0001,0.001,0.01,0.1),
                      scales::comma(10^log10(filtered_data$rel_um)))` which gives no error but ends up changing the axis label to a number. When I try to add scales as a separate layer it also won't work because it gives an error stating scales cannot be used on ggplot. I'm sorry if this is dumb, I'm not getting this.

Comment: Try `scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(-4,-3,-2,-1), labels = ~ scales::comma(10^.x))`.

Comment: Wow it works! I think I need to read up on the stats documentation, because the x throws me off. Thanks!!!

Comment: Haha. `.x` or simply `.` can be found almost everywhere in the tidyverse when using anonymous functions, i.e. you could also have done `labels = function(x) scales::comma(10^x)`. Using ´~` is shorter but in that case we need the `.x` to specify the argument.